# OpenSSL::X509::Certificate cannot open pem file - (PEM_read_bio_X509: no start line)

Tags: ruby, openssl

When I run:

```
OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDd/deZ6ncdwxUH
Qlt2IV0LAZLEouWv7ntukG2FNhouvSW7xTi3JXTio7aBnPHUVCJdN41U1cVwfbtn
...
f5SDrfUDnuALz6YBiwf8vvCl1RSV2jB9yWKxGK9FG7iT96dBM1CYQMMx6xD204YL
CE/Q5PCKGOTWxOQSpLvctN3U
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----")
```

This gives `OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError (PEM_read_bio_X509: no start line)`

Is there something I'm missing?

*(n.b. This question is a more generalized rewrite of a previous question to make it more useful to the wider community)*

Answer (score 1):

You are loading a private key there, not an X509 certificate. To load a key, you have to use the `OpenSSL::PKey` class rather than `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate` as such:

```
OpenSSL::PKey.read("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDd/deZ6ncdwxUH
Qlt2IV0LAZLEouWv7ntukG2FNhouvSW7xTi3JXTio7aBnPHUVCJdN41U1cVwfbtn
...
f5SDrfUDnuALz6YBiwf8vvCl1RSV2jB9yWKxGK9FG7iT96dBM1CYQMMx6xD204YL
CE/Q5PCKGOTWxOQSpLvctN3U
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----")
```

Please refer to [the documentation of `OpenSSL::PKey.read`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey.html#method-c-read) for details.